# Проблема с пользовательским поиском Yii2 gridwiew

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, gridview

Я пишу CRUD Приложени. Я хочу сделать поиск по полям с join.
Мой код в модели

```
  public function getIdVacancy() {
            return $this->status->id_vacancy;
        }
```

И мой код в модели поиска, это работает

```
  $query->joinWith(['status' => function ($q) {
            $q->where('status.id_vacancy LIKE "%' . $this->idVacancy . '%"');
        }]);
```

Это мой запрос значения в модели(проблема)

```
public function getVacancyNumber()
    {
        return $this->status->vacancy->code;
    }
```

Я незнаю как составить запрос для поиска по этому полю в модели поиска

Я написал вот это, но оно не работает. Я не могу понять как это сделать

```
  $query->joinWith(['status' => function ($q) {
               $vacancy_id = \backend\models\Vacancy::find()->where( 'title LIKE "%' . $this->titleVacancy . '%"')->one()->id;
                $q->where('status.id_vacancy LIKE "%' . $vacancy_id . '%"');
            }]);
```

Подскажите хоть куда думать)
Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0):

Это написано не правильно

```
  $vacancy_id = \backend\models\Vacancy::find()->where( 'title LIKE "%' . $this->titleVacancy . '%"')->one()->id;
```

Когда используете запрос с лайк прайвильно написать так :

```
  $vacancy_id = \backend\models\Vacancy::find()->where( ['like', 'title', $this->titleVacancy])->one()->id;
```

Тут не понятно

```
  public function getVacancyNumber()
        {
            return $this->status->vacancy->code;
        }
```

тут как получается, вы находитесь в модели, принимаете обьект $this
Обращаетесь к свойству status ( или связи ) которое является обьектом, где есть еще одна связь vacancy и уже у этого обьекта берете свойство code

Тут явно что то не так.